# How to remove status bar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: colors, android-jetpack-compose, hide, statusbar

I'm trying to remove the status bar from my application.

I checked several posts and many people recommend this:

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false // Status bar
systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false // Navigation bar
systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false // Status & Navigation bars
systemUiController.navigationBarDarkContentEnabled = falsee
```

inside the setContent block of Main activity.
from: com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller

The result of the above code was a black status bar.
What I would like to achieve is to remove it completely and extend the composable Screen.

What I got:

[image]

What I would like:

[image]

I wouldn't prefer to change the status bar color, since the application has screens with different background color and i would like an homogeneous result.
(Same background color, same status bar color)

Do you know if this can happen? and how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use insets https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets

Answer (score 0):

to do this you need to set your **status bar color** to `Transparent` and then `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` to `false`, how to do that?
there are two ways:

if you are using **material 3 compose** in your `themes.kt` file you should have this:

```
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        //set this to transparent
        window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
    }
}
```

if you aren't using material 3 then go to your `themes.xml` file and change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="Theme.Test" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">
        false
    </item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">
        @color/black
    </item>
    </style>
```

(you may have to add the color transparent to your colors.xml file)

after doing one of the two ways you want to go to your MainActivity and add this before the setContent function:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //add this line
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window,false)

    setContent {
        TestTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = Color.Green
            ) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below code in themes.xml of your app base theme.

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```